# Updating a variable by its id within python

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I know how to get the value of a variable by its id in Python like:

```
a = "hello world!"
ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
```

I wonder if it possible to overwrite the variables value by id?

The simplest way, this one:

```
ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value = "new value"
```

does not work.

Answer (score 10):

### Why it did not work

The object `ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object)` provides a view to an object in memory. A view is an object in its own rights. So when updating the `value` attribute you do not update the object itself, all you do is create a new object and make the `value` attribute of your view point to it.

```
import ctypes

a = "Hello World!"
py_obj = ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object)

id(py_obj.value) # 1868526529136

py_obj.value = 'Bye Bye World!'

# Here we can see that `value` now points to a new object
id(py_obj.value) # 1868528280112
```

### How to mutate any object

It is possible, with `ctypes`, to update memory directly and thus to mutate any object. That is even true for strings which are said to be immutable.

The following is interesting as an exercice, but **should never be used** in other circumstances. Among other things it can corrupt object reference count, leading to memory management errors.

```
import ctypes
import sys

def mutate(obj, new_obj):
    if sys.getsizeof(obj) != sys.getsizeof(new_obj):
        raise ValueError('objects must have same size')

    mem = (ctypes.c_byte * sys.getsizeof(obj)).from_address(id(obj))
    new_mem = (ctypes.c_byte * sys.getsizeof(new_obj)).from_address(id(new_obj))

    for i in range(len(mem)):
        mem[i] = new_mem[i]
```

Here are examples. Among these you will find reasons why **you must not use the above code** unless you really know what you are doing or as an exercice.

```
s = 'Hello World!'
mutate(s, 'Bye World!!!')
print(s) # prints: 'Bye World!!!'

# The following happens because of Python interning
mutate('a', 'b')
print('a') # prints: 'b'

mutate(1, 2)
print(1) # prints: 2
```

In particular, the above example makes Python exit with an unknown error code or crash, depending on the version and environment.

Comment: @user2357112 Which version of Python are you using, I cannot reproduce the error in your edit

Comment: 2.7.11 on Windows.

Comment: I added the version since it seems to works for Python 3.6

Comment: I get a crash on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lobjl3) as well, Python 3.5, apparently some flavor of Linux. Maybe try it in a fresh interpreter. It could have been affected by other things you did, like `mutate(1, 2)`.

Comment: Yes, mutate(1, 2) is probably the cause since it makes Python exit with code -1073740940. My guess is that by mutating an integer, we may have mutated the exit code

Comment: `mutate(1, 2)` doesn't seem to affect the crash on my setup; `mutate([1], [1])` crashes with or without `mutate(1, 2)`, and `mutate(1, 2)` doesn't (immediately) provoke a crash.

Comment: Yes, I've been toying with it a bit now and there are just so many ways to make Python crash or throw senseless errors that I don't think it's worth digging deeper.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, I couldn't get it to run without error, apparently the for loop needs to start at 1 not 0 for this to work properly in python3.6

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a string, and strings are immutable in Python.

Example from documentation:

```
>>> s = "Hello, World"
>>> c_s = c_wchar_p(s)
>>> print(c_s)
c_wchar_p(139966785747344)
>>> print(c_s.value)
Hello World
>>> c_s.value = "Hi, there"
>>> print(c_s)              # the memory location has changed
c_wchar_p(139966783348904)
>>> print(c_s.value)
Hi, there
>>> print(s)                # first object is unchanged
Hello, World
>>>
```